# How to use MQTT with Tomcat

Tags: mqtt, tomcat8

I'd like to use MQTT in tomcat8 in order to publish messages via MQTT. I use the Paho library version 3.1.1. When I try to instantiate the client using

```
String clientId = Mqtt.generateClientId(); 
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883", clientId);
```

I get an MqttException(0).

Below you'll find the details of the error message and the stacktrace:

```
reason 0
msg MqttException
loc MqttException
cause null
excep MqttException (0)
MqttException (0)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.open(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:138)
    at de.rz.homeautomation.service.HomeAutomationService.publishSensorData(HomeAutomationService.java:807)
    at de.rz.homeautomation.service.HomeAutomationService.postSensorData(HomeAutomationService.java:857)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1030)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1537)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The same code works fine in a command line program, so I guess I have to do some kind of configuration of MQTT and/or tomcat. I also don't know if I need additional libraries. I just copied the paho library in the lib-folder of WEB-INF.

Just right now I am only guessing what could be the problem.

Can somebody explain me how I have to configure tomcat or where I have to move the library?

Thanks a lot,

Rudi

Comment: Edit the question to include the whole stacktrace and any other information (like the message) from the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is being thrown when the MQTT Client tries to open the persistence file, I will assume it is probably a permisions error for the default location and the user running Tomcat.

You probably need to set the path by passing in a [MQTTDefaultFilePersistence](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/persist/MqttDefaultFilePersistence.html#MqttDefaultFilePersistence-java.lang.String-) object to the MQTTClient() constructor after the client ID or pass in a [MemoryPersistence](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/persist/MemoryPersistence.html#MemoryPersistence--) to remove the need to store to disk at all (this will potentially loose messages if Tomcat crashes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint. Since I just need to send occasional messages and do not need to recover messages in case of a problem I used a MemoryPersistence and it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot!